# Trying to setup Travis, breaks before install

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, runtime-error, travis-ci

I was trying to setup Travis for my github project but run into some problems (see SS). I have tried some different ways in .travis.yml for example like this below but it doesn't work:

```js
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "8.11.2"
sudo: false
before_install:
  - npm install
notifications:
  email:
on_success: never
```

Travis error:
https://gyazo.com/09f7ad5e0062121449577c726b565dee

I get a feeling that it tries to run some java stuff or something, not sure though... help is appreciated! If you need to know something more let me know please, the app is built in a folder which contains two folder, one front and one backend. it's JS, express, React

Comment: Could you post a link to the build log? If it is a private repository, could you reproduce the error on a public build and share the link?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do this but I don't get it why didn't it work? I followed tutorial for it

Comment: sry for second comment but why does it say build.xml doesnt exsist

Comment: @joepd Not sure if you get notice ^

Comment: I do not continuously monitor notifications here. Repeated question. Could you post a link to the build log?

Answer (score 0):

I now get this:
https://gyazo.com/03943c7340cc33bcc6967c5e9a5468d7
I'll edit my post in a while with more content